# Why can not I add class

Tags: jquery, css

Why classes "markO" and "markX" is not append to the found item?

```
 function buldTicTacToeUI(gameState) {
 var html ='<div id="game">';
    for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
        html += ("<span id=" + i + " class='box' />");
    }
    html += '</div>';
    if (gameState.X != null) {
        for (var i = 0; i < gameState.X.length; i++) {
            $(html).find("#game .box#" + gameState.X[i]).addClass("markX");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it entered the if-statement? Please make a jsFiddle...

Comment: Spans ids are 1-9 if gameState.X[i] is not 1-9 then it wont find the spans

Comment: IDs must be unique on context page, so use directly ID selector, no need to use 'complex' selector here: `$(#" + gameState.X[i]).addClass("markX");`

Answer (score 2):

You could just do it like that i guess:

```
function buldTicTacToeUI(gameState) {
    var html = '<div id="game">';
    for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
        html += ("<span id=" + i + " class='box" + (gameState.X != null ? " markX" : "") + "' />");
    }
    html += '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `append` the html string to the DOM prior to finding it with jQuery.

```
 function buldTicTacToeUI(gameState) {
 var html ='<div id="game">';
    for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
        html += ("<span id=" + i + " class='box' />");
    }
    html += '</div>';
    $(document).append(html); //append where you prefer
    if (gameState.X != null) {
        for (var i = 0; i < gameState.X.length; i++) {
            $("#game .box #" + gameState.X[i]).addClass("markX");
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: You don't need to append to find elements with jQuery

Comment: Hi Kevin! You've missed the fact that he maybe declaring the IDs differently, from how he searches for them.

Answer (score 1):

Strange way to find the `gameState[i]` cell.

```
$(html).find("#game .box#" + gameState.X[i])
```

The above doesn't match the IDs you declared.. you declared the element IDs as `i` being an integer from 1 to 9, but then you're expecting id to match gameState.X[i]. You should also quote the ID properly.

ID selectors may only work when the elements are actually in the DOM -- at this stage here you've built them, but not appended them. Appending before you try & search for them, would probably be sensible.

Additionally, this is a complicated selector -- where just selecting on ID (without requiring the parent, or the class) would be simpler & more efficient.

Here's a better way to do it, using unambiguous 'cellN' element IDs:

```
function buldTicTacToeUI (gameState) {
    var html ='<div id="game">';
    for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
        html += "<span id='cell"+i+"' class='box' />";
    }
    html += '</div>';
    var result = $(html);
    result.appendTo( 'body');  // or wherever you want to put it
    if (gameState.X != null) {
        for (var i = 0; i < gameState.X.length; i++) {
            var cellNum = gameState.X[i];   // is this a cell number?
            $("#cell"+cellNum).addClass("markX");
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: what I forgot to write that I function buldTicTacToeUI () to return the html variable with the added classes. Is there a way to do so, or should happen outside the function where I add html variable

Comment: ID is a property of the DOM, and may not be reliable when you try & use it outside. This is a trivial task to do, so long as you work with your tools (& build/return a DOM element), rather than against them (trying to return a string).